# ggplot second and third x axis for different parameters

Tags: ggplot2, axis

I am trying to plot three different types of data in one ggplot.
The types are activity, temperature and chlorophyll. So I need two more x-axes,
one for temperature and one for chlorophyll.

The code I use at the moment is

```
ggplot(S22,
  aes(x=activity,
       y= depth_m,
       color= Temperature)) +
   labs(title="alkaline phosphatase_S22", y = "depth [m]") +
   xlab(expression(paste("activity [nmol", " ",l^-1, " ", h^-1, "]", sep=""))) + 
   scale_color_manual(values = c("blue","red"),
                   breaks=c("c", "w"),
                   labels=c("1.8°C", "5.8°C"))+
   scale_y_continuous(trans=reverselog_trans(10),  
       breaks = c(0,5,10,25,50,100,250,500,1000)) + geom_point()
   #scale_x_continuous(position = "top") +
geom_path(data=Chl22d, aes(x=Fluorometer_V, y=depth_m), color='green') +
geom_path(data=Chl22d, aes(x=T_C, y=depth_m), color= 'darkgrey')
```

I read, that I could use the scale_x_continous function. But that won´t work.
Does anyone have an idea? Is this even possible with ggplot?
Thanks so much in advance

Comment: sorry, but it's not very clear to me what you are trying to achieve. What is a graph with three x-axes ? Could you clarify ?

Comment: I have three different parameters in different units. I would like an x-axis or scale for each of them. For example, two on the the bottom of the plot and one on top.

Comment: Well, that would make for a VERY confusing plot, IMHO. Maybe using facets to build three separate graphs would be better.

Comment: In that specific context it actually makes sense. I appreciate your advice, though. Maybe that is something to thing about.

Comment: Then there's no way I know to do that in ggplot. You could manage to have two by using `sec_axis` in the call to `scale_x_continuous`, but I don't think there's an easy way to have three.

Comment: Ok. I will think of a trick to circumnavigate the problem. Thank you for your help.